# Expand item in NSOutlineView with NSTreeController

Tags: swift, objective-c, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to get the node from a disclosure button clicked

I think this function is the more appropriate:

```
func outlineViewItemDidExpand(_ notification: Notification) {
     
     let nodeToExpand = notification.userInfo as! Node
     let nodeToExpand2 = notification.userInfo["NSObject"] as! Node

    //Error @selector(_outlineControlClicked:) from sender NSButton 0x10053d710

}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to expand the node from code or do you want to be notified when the user expands the node?

Comment: I need to get the URL assigned to this node (Node.url) in order to append childrenNode to his parentNode.

Comment: What is preventing you from getting the URL from `nodeToExpand2`?

Comment: This is the error message when I try code upper : -->

"Could not cast value of type 'NSKVONotifying_NSTreeControllerTreeNode' (0x600003018b40) to 'Editor.Node' (0x100040720). Performing @selector(_outlineControlClicked:) from sender NSButton 0x100649c90"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSTreeController` wraps your nodes in `NSTreeNode` objects. Your node is `representedObject` of the `NSTreeNode`.

```
if let treeNode = notification.userInfo["NSObject"] as? NSTreeNode,
   let node = treeNode.representedObject as? Node {
    …
}
```